# LightDM GTK+ greeter doesn't use the right cursor theme

Tags: debian, theme, lightdm, alternatives

I'm trying to define Suru++ as the cursor theme for LightDM GTK+ greeter on Debian stretch. This is supposedly done by adding Suru++ to the list of alternatives for x-cursor-theme, and choosing it as the alternative:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme x-cursor-theme /usr/share/icons/Suru++/cursor.theme 0
user@debian:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
There are 4 choices for the alternative x-cursor-theme (providing /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme).

  Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme   102       auto mode
  1            /etc/X11/cursors/Breeze_Snow.theme      41        manual mode
  2            /etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme   102       manual mode
  3            /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursor.theme   90        manual mode
* 4            /usr/share/icons/Suru++/cursor.theme    0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

If I pick any alternative in that list other than Suru++, the cursor used by LightDM GTK+ greeter is the one from the selected alternative. However, when I pick **Suru++** as the alternative in the list, the cursor used by LightDM GTK+ greeter is from the **Adwaita** theme. This behaviour is weird to me because Suru doesn't inherit anything from Adwaita as far as I can see. In fact the contents of `/usr/share/icons/Suru++/cursor.theme` are very simple:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name = Suru
Comment = A Suru-like cursor designed by Sam Hewitt
Inherits = Suru
```

How should make the LightDM GTK+ greeter use this particular cursor theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the value of the `Inherits` option in `cursor.theme` didn't match the name of the directory containing the theme.

Setting `Inherits` to **Suru++** instead of **Suru** solved the problem.